# mysql fetch return only return most recent row in class

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySql class and I fetch the Mysql rows by returning them as a method:

```
  public function fetch_assoc($result_set){
     return mysql_fetch_assoc($result_set);
  }
```

For some reason it only return one result when I try to iterate through an method return through the object I have instantiated.

```
  while ($row = $a->fetch_assoc($result_set){
  ...
  }
```

While doing the old fashion ways works, and gives me all the rows

```
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)){
      $row['0'];
  }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting.  Did you try copying the result to a var before returning?
public function fetch_assoc($result_set){
     $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_set);
     return $row;
  }

Comment: This isn't entirely related to the question. But if you are writing new code, you may not want to use the deprecated mysql API. There are better alternatives. PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php MySQL-Improved: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Btw, maybe this is just a copy/paste error, but you are missing a parenthesis in your `while` loop. ` while ($row = $a->fetch_assoc($result_set){` should be ` while ($row = $a->fetch_assoc($result_set)){`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because mysql_fetch_assoc return only one result and moves the pointer to the next. So at each iteration it returns moves the pointer and returns false when it reaches the end of the results.

You can modify your method this way to make it work:

```
public function fetch_assoc($result_set){
    $resultArray = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_set){
        $resultArray[] = $row;
    }
    return $resultArray;
}
```

And you can use the data as so:

```
foreach ($obj->fetch_assoc($result_set) as $row){
    echo $row['stuff'];
}
```

Note that in this case `$obj->fetch_assoc($result_set)` returns all the results, and i am just looping through it using a foreach loop;

Comment: A better way would be to model the resultset as an iterator, which can call the fetch function when it is iterated over.

Comment: @Sven if thats the case, might aswell stick with `mysql_fetch_assoc`

Comment: It seems as though he knows `mysql_fetch_assoc` only fetches one row at a time. He has a `while` loop to fetch all the elements, but he says it still doesn't work. It makes me wonder if his `$result_set` variable isn't being modified correctly with the extra layer of indirection.